# How do I set MaxConcepts for when calling postModelOutputs in latest version of Java API?

Tags: clarifai

Can anyone point me to the documentation or an example on the subject?
I'm using one of the standard models so I assume there should be away to set this as a parameter.
I've tried to set it as follows:

```
generalModel = Model.newBuilder(generalModel)
                    .setOutputInfo(OutputInfo.newBuilder(model.getOutputInfo())
                        .setOutputConfig(OutputConfig.newBuilder(model.getOutputInfo().getOutputConfig())
                            .setMaxConcepts(200)
                            .build())
                        .build())
                    .build()
```

but it doesn't respect the MaxConcepts count

Answer (score 0):

I found this documentation: [Prediction Parameters](https://docs.clarifai.com/api-guide/predict/prediction-parameters#maximum-concepts).

The example from this documentation, includes this code:

```
MultiOutputResponse postModelOutputsResponse = stub.postModelOutputs(
    PostModelOutputsRequest.newBuilder()
        .setModelId("aaa03c23b3724a16a56b629203edc62c")  // This is model ID of the clarifai/main General model.
        .addInputs(
            Input.newBuilder().setData(
                Data.newBuilder().setImage(
                    Image.newBuilder().setUrl("https://samples.clarifai.com/metro-north.jpg")
                )
            )
        )
        .setModel(
            Model.newBuilder().setOutputInfo(
                OutputInfo.newBuilder().setOutputConfig(
                    OutputConfig.newBuilder().setMaxConcepts(3)
                )
            )
        )
        .build()
);
```

It seems the main difference is that they call `build()` only once. I haven't tested it, but I guess that shouldn't bring any change.